# What are these wires visible in Space Shuttle ODS/APAS-95?

Tags: space-shuttle, identify-this-object, docking, docking-port

What are these three wires connected in a y-shape called and what is their role? Some sort of alignment guide? Sorry for the hard to see picture.
[image]

Comment: Broken link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=howtohotwirespaceshuttle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That y-cable assembly was called the "centerline camera crosshair". It worked in conjunction with the docking camera below it and the docking target on the ISS.

[image]
(Image [source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-optical-sighting-system-such-as-the-ISS-docking-target-could-prove-useful-for-a-crewed_fig4_287182593))

The crew would use the centerline camera to view the relative alignment of the crosshair and the docking target during the final stage of rendezvous/docking.

Reference: [Orbital docking system centerline color television camera system test](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19940020152/downloads/19940020152.pdf)

The best drawings I could find with the crosshair labeled:

[image]

[image]

From [Space Shuttle Systems Handbook Volume 3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/shuttleultra/files/References/JSC-1117%20-%20Space_Shuttle_Systems_Handbook_Vol2.pdf/download), pages 389 and 391 in the pdf.

There is some video of the centerline camera crosshairs at 4:18 in this STS-86 postflight video (in this case the station shown is the Mir).